# encrypted cloud storage with partial local copy

Tags: encryption, cloud-computing, storage

Is there a cloud storage solution with the following features:

- partially copied locally. Not fully like dropbox so it can be larger than the local disk. Not fully in the cloud but just a local disk for recent data, i.e. its fast and works offline.
- good client side encryption. No possibility or temptation for the host to decrypt my files.
- can be shared by multiple machines
- optionally some backup mechanism.
- osx support, iOS optionally

I imagine a large client side encrypted virtual disk with partial local backup, i.e. encfs with an intelligent sync to cloud.

Answer (score 2):

While not a direct answer to your question, my personal suggestion would be to use a standard file hosting service that meets your needs and perform your own client side encryption and decryption.  This is really the only way you can know for sure that the service provider doesn't have any way to be able to access your data.  This opens up the door for you to be able to have much more control of the security of your data while also being able to use a much broader set of service providers to find one that meets your needs overall.

Answer (score 0):

JustCloud is one solution that has all these features. JustCloud can be shared by multiple machines, has an optional backup mechanism and has osx support. To find a cloud storage platform that fits your needs, I found this useful blog post that has listed many storage services with all their features and specifications.

Source: http://www.cloudreviews.com/blog/best-cloud-storage-providers

Comment: Can you provide some extra detail on how their encryption works? I only found marketing bullshit on their website.

Comment: I updated your post to try to make it easier to read as I understood your intent.

Comment: justcloud does not use client side encryption. In their conditions of use they state: "JustCloud enforces content recognition and filtering and a manual review of files backed up and stored.", i.e they can an will look at the content. I will look at the blog for more ideas.